# css - menu loses height after a few rollovers

Tags: jquery, css

We have a live site and a dev reskin which uses the same menu, but for some reason the dev version has a peculiar issue with the top slide down menu, i.e. if you roll over it a few times, it starts losing height.

Dev version: http://ithea.jwgecko.com/index.cfm
Live site: http://ithea.vic.edu.au/

Any ideas what could be the problem?

Comment: it's fine .......... what problum .........

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a CSS issue but a jQuery one

Comment: There is a javascript problem. I think that on mouse enter there are made some calculations about the height of the active menu. So if you move to fast between menus the menu height is not correctly assigned.

Comment: @user460114: See my answer with a possible solution.

Comment: On your ul.sub-menu of student information the property css height is equal to 1px.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems **jQuery** library version (1.7.1) issue.

Change your **jQuery** library version greater than 1.7.1

[**SEE AN EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/mN6Hk/) - <sup>[ *Using jQuery Library 1.7.2* ]</sup>

**Additional Notes:**

The menu you are using on live is a **super fish menu** and on dev site is a custom menu. So both menus are different.